# Cannot delete organization -deletion is not allowed until all environments are deleted

Tags: apigee

I would like to delete an organization called "test". It had few environments, but I previously deleted all of them. However, when I try now to delete the organization, I get the following error:

```
curl -u $creds "$url/o/test" -X DELETE
{
"code" : "messaging.config.beans.OrgHasEnvironments",
"message" : "Organization test has some environments. Deletion is not allowed until all environments are deleted.",
"contexts" : [ ]
}
```

However checking as below shows there are **no** environments currently in this org.

```
curl -u $creds "http://$HOSTIP:8080/v1/o/test/environments"
[ ]
```

What should I do in order to successfully delete the "test" organization?

Thank you!

Comment: This API works in the current version.  Which version of the product are you on now?

Answer (score 0):

If this operation is not working for you through the API, it would need to be deleted through Zookeeper, which is a tricky operation and best to be avoided.  You would be better off creating a new org with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer! 
Yes, I already tried to delete through Zookeeper, but as I don't know exactly how ZK is used and what is the nodes' tree, I ended up messing things around. I re-created the deleted node as the GUI was not anymore functional (I don't remember the error).

The actual reason why I wanted to completely erase that org is because I messed up the virtual hosts and the requests were wrongly routed.